# Spark - Scala - Replacing value in dataframe with lookup value from another data frame

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I'm working with Spark on Databricks. The programming language is Scala.

I have two data frames:

- Main data frame: See screenshot: [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EShir.png)
- Lookup data frame: See screenshot [3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DHQY1.png)

I would like to:

- Find all rows where "Age"==-1 in the main dataframe
- Look at the "title" value of that row
- Look in dataframe 2 to see which the average age for people with this title is
- Update the age in the main dataframe with this value.

I've wrecked my head on how to do this. The only thing I came up with was storing the dataframe as a table in databricks and using SQL statements (sql.Context.Sql...), which ended up being very complicated.

I'm wondering if there's a more efficient way of doing this.

**Edit: Adding reproducible example**

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
val df = sc.parallelize(Seq(("Fred", 20, "Intern"), ("Linda", -1, "Manager"),  ("Sean", 23, "Junior Employee"), ("Walter", 35, "Manager"), ("Kate", -1, "Junior Employee"), ("Kathrin", 37, "Manager"), ("Bob", 16, "Intern"), ("Lukas", 24, "Junionr Employee")))
    .toDF("Name", "Age", "Title")

println("Data Frame DF")
df.show();


val avgAge = df.filter("Age!=-1").groupBy("Title").agg(avg("Age").alias("avg_age")).toDF()
println("Average Ages")
avgAge.show()

println("Missing Age")
val noAge = df.filter("Age==-1").toDF()
noAge.show()
```

**Solution thanks to Karol Sudol**

```
val imputedAges = df.filter("Age == -1").join(avgAge, Seq("Title")).select(col("Name"),col("avg_age"), col("Title") )
imputedAges.show()

val finalDF= imputedAges.union(df.filter("Age!=-1"))
println("FinalDF")
finalDF.show()
```

Comment: please share a reproducible example.

Comment: I'll work on an example that's not a total mess. Wil update as soon as I have it.

Answer (score 3):

```
val df = dfMain.filter("age == -1").join(dfLookUp, Seq("title")).select(col("title"), col("avg"), ......)
```

use `left/right/outer join` on the next step with `main DF` if you want to retain any other values.

go through tutorials: [databricks training](https://docs.databricks.com/spark/latest/training/index.html)

Comment: Thanks! This worked (see my update of the original question). The column "Age" is now titled "avg_age", but it still has the original ages where age was present. Also, thanks for the link to the videos. Very helpful.